# How can I remove my me.com address from Mail?

Tags: icloud, email

I have a few email accounts set up in Mail. One of them is my *xxxxx*@mac.com email address. At some point (maybe after I switched to iCloud), Mail started including the *xxxxx*@me.com address in the list of potential from: addresses. Is there any way to convince it to not include the @me.com address? I don't ever want to use it.

**Edit**

Sorry, I may have been unclear. I want to continue using the *xxxxx*@mac.com address. I just don't want the *xxxxx*@me.com address in the popup list or to have Mail automatically enter it in the From field when I create a new message.

Comment: If it were me, I'd simply remove the account.  Is that not an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you just want to remove the "@me" from the "from" drop down when creating an email (I found this excruciatingly annoying), go to Preferences, Account Information, and then in the Email Address field, delete the "@me" address, so that only your cool .Mac is in there.

Comment: GET OUT!! What f**ed-up mental block did I have that kept me from trying that? I'm so happy to give you your first accepted answer.

Comment: These days, cannot delete the .me account, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Mail's Preferences / Accounts / Advanced** and deselect the *Activate this account* checkbox. This should do the trick.

Comment: You need to restart Mail for this to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove the account and all associated data from your hard drive.

Go to:
Mail > Preferences

[image]

In the tab choose Accounts:

[image]

Chose your .me account:

[image]

Here you can remove it with the - button

Then in the popup simply choose to remove:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but maybe try this:

- In your iCloud account preferences in Mail, click on the ""Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)" menu
- Choose "Edit SMTP Server List"
- Add a server for smtp.mac.com
- Use default ports
- Set Authentication to "password" and enter your @mac.com username and password
- Choose the server you just set up as the server for your mac.com account

That setup works for me to send from mac.com instead of me.com, but I'm not sure if that's because it was somehow grandfathered in or not. Curious to know if it works for you.